# How to write the path to the *. Bib at the natbib package?

Tags: natbib, paths

I'm working on a paper and need to cite the literature that is in a different folder to the one used at work. How to write the correct path to the *.bib at the natbib package?. Thanks

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[spanish, english]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize {3,5cm}{3,5cm}{2cm}{2cm} 
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pretolerance=2000
\tolerance=3000
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\title{TÍTULO}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\begin{flushleft}
{\footnotesize \normalsize \textbf{Palabras Clave:}}  \\
{\footnotesize \normalsize \textbf{Mathematics Subjet Classification:}}
\end{flushleft} 
\end{abstract}
\section{Antecedentes existentes para la Tesis}
\label{Antecedentes existentes para la Tesis}
\cite{raey,Zopounidis00b}


\section{Plan de Trabajo}
\label{Plan de Trabajo}
\subsection{Objetivos}
\label{Objetivos}
\subsubsection{Objetivos generales}
\label{Objetivos generales}
\subsubsection{Objetivos particulares}
\label{Objetivos particulares} 
\subsection{Metodología a seguir}
\label{Metodología a seguir} 
\section{Fundamentación de la originalidad}
\label{Fundamentación de la originalidad}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{C:/Users/Referencias/Referencias Tesis.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try `\bibliography{"C:/Users/Referencias/Referencias Tesis.bib"}` with quotes?

Comment: Don't use spaces in file names

Comment: Thank´s Joseph but it doesn´t work.

Comment: Hernán - I think @JosephWright is suggesting you rename your file to avoid the space, so that you can avoid the Bibtex-can't-handle-spaces-properly-in-paths mess with your `\bibliography` command.

Comment: I tried all your suggestions but I still can not operate

Comment: @Hernán you may need to be more specific - what doesn't work? are you getting an error message or just not getting your bibliography?  If so what error and when?